# How can I remove all objects which are having `areWeCreatingNewUser` property

Tags: javascript

I have the following object

```
const obj = {
    "title": "sample",
    "status": 0,
    "creationDate": null,
    "userGroup": "",
    "signatureDelay": "2023-06-05T11:07:18.786Z",
    "listSign": [],
    "priority": false,
    "nature": null,
    "qesData": {
        "signatories": [
            {
                "displayName": "Some user",
                "email": "someuser@hotmail.com",
                "firstname": "User first name",
                "id": "4ffb81f6-6efd-4e41-9168-b032ab3e3b04",
                "lastname": "User last name",
                "locale": "en",
                "signatoryAttributes": []
            },
            {
                "email": "test@hotmail.com",
                "displayName": "",
                "areWeCreatingNewUser": true
            },
            {
                "email": "test1@hotmail.com",
                "displayName": "",
                "areWeCreatingNewUser": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "fileName": "sample.pdf",
}
```

I need to loop through the `qesData => signatories` array and remove all of the objects there which are having `areWeCreatingNewUser` property set to true.

So I tried

```
for(var i = 0;i < obj.qesData.signatories.length;i++) {
            if(obj.qesData.signatories[i].areWeCreatingNewUser) {
                obj.qesData.signatories.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
```

the problem here is that the first time when it founds the user with email `test@hotmail.com` it remove it with splice at index 1 and after that the obj.qesData.signatories is modified and on next iteration it does not remove the user with email `test1@hotmail.com`

How can I solve this issue ?

Also I forgot to mention that I need to use old javascript code,filter is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Array.filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do it

```js
const obj = {
    "title": "sample",
    "status": 0,
    "creationDate": null,
    "userGroup": "",
    "signatureDelay": "2023-06-05T11:07:18.786Z",
    "listSign": [],
    "priority": false,
    "nature": null,
    "qesData": {
        "signatories": [
            {
                "displayName": "Some user",
                "email": "someuser@hotmail.com",
                "firstname": "User first name",
                "id": "4ffb81f6-6efd-4e41-9168-b032ab3e3b04",
                "lastname": "User last name",
                "locale": "en",
                "signatoryAttributes": []
            },
            {
                "email": "test@hotmail.com",
                "displayName": "",
                "areWeCreatingNewUser": true
            },
            {
                "email": "test1@hotmail.com",
                "displayName": "",
                "areWeCreatingNewUser": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "fileName": "sample.pdf",
}

obj.qesData.signatories = obj.qesData.signatories.filter(d => !d.areWeCreatingNewUser)
console.log(obj)
```

---

Update: for `ES5` style,below is a reference for you

```js
const obj = {
    "title": "sample",
    "status": 0,
    "creationDate": null,
    "userGroup": "",
    "signatureDelay": "2023-06-05T11:07:18.786Z",
    "listSign": [],
    "priority": false,
    "nature": null,
    "qesData": {
        "signatories": [
            {
                "displayName": "Some user",
                "email": "someuser@hotmail.com",
                "firstname": "User first name",
                "id": "4ffb81f6-6efd-4e41-9168-b032ab3e3b04",
                "lastname": "User last name",
                "locale": "en",
                "signatoryAttributes": []
            },
            {
                "email": "test@hotmail.com",
                "displayName": "",
                "areWeCreatingNewUser": true
            },
            {
                "email": "test1@hotmail.com",
                "displayName": "",
                "areWeCreatingNewUser": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "fileName": "sample.pdf",
}

let data = []
for(d of obj.qesData.signatories){
   if(!d.areWeCreatingNewUser){
     data.push(d)
   }
}

obj.qesData.signatories = data
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I can't use filter method because I need to use old js syntax - ES5

Answer (score 1):

You can use a filter to only have objects where `areWeCreatingNewUser` is not `true`

```js
obj.qesData.signatories = obj.qesData.signatories.filter(signatory =>
signatory.areWeCreatingNewUser !== true);
```

Comment: I can't use filter method because I need to use old js syntax - ES5

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` method

```js
const obj = {
    "title": "sample",
    "status": 0,
    "creationDate": null,
    "userGroup": "",
    "signatureDelay": "2023-06-05T11:07:18.786Z",
    "listSign": [],
    "priority": false,
    "nature": null,
    "qesData": {
        "signatories": [
            {
                "displayName": "Some user",
                "email": "someuser@hotmail.com",
                "firstname": "User first name",
                "id": "4ffb81f6-6efd-4e41-9168-b032ab3e3b04",
                "lastname": "User last name",
                "locale": "en",
                "signatoryAttributes": []
            },
            {
                "email": "test@hotmail.com",
                "displayName": "",
                "areWeCreatingNewUser": true
            },
            {
                "email": "test1@hotmail.com",
                "displayName": "",
                "areWeCreatingNewUser": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "fileName": "sample.pdf",
}

obj.qesData.signatories = obj.qesData.signatories.filter(item => !item.areWeCreatingNewUser);
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I can't use filter method because I need to use old javascript code

Comment: @SrushtiI can't use filter method because I need to use old js syntax - ES5